# Ошибка TypeError: document.body is null

Tags: javascript, html, html5, pug

Не понимаю что не так.. вроде всё правильно сделал. Страницу отображает, но выдаёт в консоли firefox ошибку эту. Стоит ли волноваться?
Вроде все отступы поставлены правильно, может я не вижу просто:)
Заранее спасибо за помощь!)

Добавить я хотел preloader на сайт.
вот код:

```
document.body.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var preloader = document.getElementById('page-preloader');
        if( !preloader.classList.contains('done'))
        {
            preloader.classList.add('done');
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

pug code

```
 doctype html
    html(lang="en")
        head
            meta(charset="UTF-8")
            meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
            meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="ie=edge")
            link(rel="stylesheet", href="css/main.min.css")
            link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous")
            link(href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet")
            script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js")
            script(src="js/common.js")
            title Веб дизайн
        body
            #page-preloader
                #loader
            .container
                header.main-header.grid
                    .main-menu
                        nav.menu(role="Navigation")
                            ul
                                li
                                    a(href="#") Главная
                                        img.menu-icons(src="../img/menu-icons/home.svg", alt="")
                                li
                                    a(href="#") Услуги
                                        img.menu-icons(src="../img/menu-icons/tools.svg", alt="")
                                    ul
                                        li
                                            a(href="#") Установка Windowss
                                                img.sub-menu-icons(src="../img/menu-icons/i-windows.png", alt="")
                                        li
                                            a(href="#") Удаление вирусов
                                                img.sub-menu-icons(src="../img/menu-icons/virus.png", alt="")
                                        li
                                            a(href="#") Настройка Wi-Fi
                                                img.sub-menu-icons(src="../img/menu-icons/wifi.png", alt="")
                                        li
                                            a(href="#") Настройка компьютера
                                                img.sub-menu-icons(src="../img/menu-icons/settings.png", alt="")
                                        li
                                            a(href="#") Ремонт компьютера
                                                img.sub-menu-icons(src="../img/menu-icons/repair.png", alt="")
                                        li
                                            a(href="#") Установка драйверов
                                                img.sub-menu-icons(src="../img/menu-icons/i-drivers.png", alt="")
                                        li
                                            a(href="#") Установка программ
                                                img.sub-menu-icons(src="../img/menu-icons/i-programs.png", alt="")
                                        li
                                            a(href="#") Сборка компьютеров
                                                img.sub-menu-icons(src="../img/menu-icons/processor.png", alt="")
                                        li
                                            a(href="#") Обслуживание компьютеров
                                                img.sub-menu-icons(src="../img/menu-icons/assembly-comp.png", alt="")
                                li
                                    a(href="#") Цены
                                        img.menu-icons(src="../img/menu-icons/money.png", alt="")
                                li
                                    a(href="#") Контакты
                                        img.menu-icons(src="../img/menu-icons/contact.svg", alt="")
                                li
                                    a(href="#") О нас
                                        img.menu-icons(src="../img/menu-icons/o-nas.svg", alt="")
                    .logo.black
                        h1 It-Fishki
                    .right-header.black
                        a(href="#")
                            .inner-header
                                p Позвонить (097) 528-26-72
                section.main-content-1.grid
                    .content
                        img(src="../img/liakad_piranha.png", alt="piranha")
                        p Добро пожаловать IT-FISHKA. МЫ ЛУЧШИЕ В УКРАИНЕ!

                section.main-content-2.grid
                footer.main-footer.grid
                    .1-foot
                        p lol
                    .2-foot
                        p lol
```

Comment: Нужно или весь скрипт разместить внутри `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ сюда });` — чтобы оно срабатывало после загрузки страницы... Или разместить скрипт  где-то ниже body.

Comment: Ну да, вы поставили скрипт перед body, и во время выполнения скрипта никакого body, очевидно, ещё не появилось

Comment: Спасибо, это было верно!